How to get Apple App Store reviews - xml feed is gone
The reviews for an app on the AppStore where accessable via rss-feed
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=284862083/sortBy=mostHelpful/page=1/json
This site now redirects to the App Store. Did Apple close this endpoint or are the reviews accessable at a different endpoint now?

did you find a new url? part of our system relied on this endpoint...

@FrancoMuñiz seems like the endpoint is accessable again

yep! btw in case it ever breaks again, if you remove the country code part and you add ?cc=code (for example, ?cc=us) as a query param, it seems to work as expected

I ran into the same issue, but the RSS feed is available again for my app now. Maybe yours as well?

You can get them using the AppStoreConnect APIs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_customer_reviews_for_an_app

But this does not allow to monitor reviews from external apps
